# No Audio in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, Realtek ALC892

Tags: drivers, sound, compiling, alsa

This is my first venture into using Linux. Things have been mostly smooth, but I have run into an issue with sound: there is none.

I have checked this site, Google, and various other areas to no avail. I am by no means a novice user, but as stated above I am largely ignorant to how Linux handles driver compiles and installation. Any help, even just a point in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated!

- System:

  - AMD Ryzen 1700X
  - MSI X370 SLI Plus Motherboard with Realtek ALC892 chipset.
  - OS: Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, Kernel: 4.11.0

Everything works so far except there is no sound. I have followed several guides that have claimed [SOLVED] on the issue but no luck for me. The most recent guide I have tried has been Realteks own, included in the Linux 3.0 Driver package.

The Realtek HD Audio device shows in BIOS and is enabled. However the hardware device does not show up once i boot into Linux. In sound settings only "Dummy Output" is shown as a virtual device. No hardware device is detected. I am assuming this is because the driver failed to install correctly in Ubuntu. The device outputs sound just fine in Windows 7 and 10.

Following their guide, I end up with a few errors in the `./config`, `make`, and make `install` steps. I'll include the output here.

I am sure that the sound issue is due to this driver install process ailing, but I am not sure how to fix it.

---

Some of the errors I encountered:

```
checking for kernel version... 4.11.0-041100-generic
checking for GCC version... Kernel compiler:  Used compiler: gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406
*** NO PREDEFINED KERNEL COMPILER IS DETECTED
*** Assuming the same compiler is used with the current system compiler.
*** Please make sure that the same compiler version was used for building kernel.
checking for built-in ALSA... no
checking for existing ALSA module... yes
```

---

```
error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
"Compiled on " __DATE__ " for kernel %s"
```

---

```
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

---

```
make[1]: Entering directory '~/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore'
mkdir -p /lib/modules/4.11.0-041100-generic/kernel/sound/acore
cp snd-hrtimer.ko snd-hwdep.ko snd-page-alloc.ko snd-pcm.ko snd-rawmidi.ko snd-timer.ko snd.ko /lib/modules/4.11.0-041100-generic/kernel/sound/acore
cp: cannot stat 'snd-hrtimer.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-hwdep.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-page-alloc.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-pcm.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-rawmidi.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-timer.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd.ko': No such file or directory
~/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/Rules.make:48: recipe for target 'modules_install' failed
make[1]: *** [modules_install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '~/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore'
Makefile:206: recipe for target 'install-modules' failed
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
```

Comment: You shouldn't be compiling or messing with drivers and other stuff without proper troubleshooting. Does HDMI audio works (if present)? What devices are shown in sound settings and are the intended one correctly selected? Also have you checked UEFI (BIOS replacement) settings? Most if not all onboard devices can be there enabled/disabled... This is just the start...

Comment: There is no HDMI device. Device shown is Dummy Output, no hardware item detected. All motherboard devices are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can install PulseAudio Volume Control using command :

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Run it, and go to the Configuration menu, select Analog Stereo Duplex on profile.

Then, go to Output Devices. Try Line Out or Headphones options until your speaker is normal.

Comment: Installed, not sure how to access the configuration menu. The one included in the toolbar only shows "Dummy Output".

Comment: Found the configuration menu for pulse, it says the same as the sound settings in System. Dummy Output. No hardware device is being detected, probably due to the Realtek driver not installing correctly.  Not sure how to get it to install correctly.